# Python: rolling an array multiple times and saving each iteration as an image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have multiple images that I am taking in with a for loop. I want to obtain 5 pseudo-layers for each image by rolling the initial by one pixel in both x and y and saving the rolled image each time.

I'm practicing with one image making sure I can get five layers out of it but no joy.

My code is below but it is only saving the first image; output is pl_0.tif

```
list_frames = glob.glob('*.gif')
for index, fname in enumerate(list_frames):
    im = Image.open(fname)
    shift=1
    imary0 = np.array(im) # initial image (first layer)
    imary1x = np.roll(imary0, shift, axis=0) # shift image by one pixel to create second layer
    imary1xy = np.roll(imary1x, shift, axis=1)
    imary2x = np.roll(imary1xy, shift, axis=0) # shift previous image again to create third layer
    imary2xy = np.roll(imary2x, shift, axis=1)
    imary3x = np.roll(imary2xy, shift, axis=0) # shift previous image again to create fourth layer
    imary3xy = np.roll(imary3x, shift, axis=1)
    imary4x = np.roll(imary3xy, shift, axis=0) # shift previous image again to create fifth layer
    imary4xy = np.roll(imary4x, shift, axis=1)
    im0 = Image.fromarray(imary0)
    im0.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
    im1 = Image.fromarray(imary1xy)
    im1.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
    im2 = Image.fromarray(imary2xy)
    im2.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
    im3 = Image.fromarray(imary3xy)
    im3.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
    im4 = Image.fromarray(imary4xy)
    im4.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
    im.close()
```

Any suggestions? (And please feel free to ridicule me if this is an easy fix)

Comment: what makes you think `'pl_{}.tif'.format(index)` would give different results if you call it several times?

Comment: @njzk2: the answer is: too many long hours seeing the same code without a coffee break.

Comment: You should be able to combine the `roll` calls into single lines, and use a for loop to write the files, which it looks like that's what you're trying to do there

Comment: unfortunately so @Jean-FrançoisFabre! but I'm also still learning so I'll take all and any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save all 5 images in the same output file, which means that you get only one image, `im4`

```
im0.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
im1 = Image.fromarray(imary1xy)
im1.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
im2 = Image.fromarray(imary2xy)
im2.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
im3 = Image.fromarray(imary3xy)
im3.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
im4 = Image.fromarray(imary4xy)
im4.save('pl_{}.tif'.format(index))
```

(note that index is not modified until next loop)

quickfix:

```
im0.save('pl_{}0.tif'.format(index))
im1 = Image.fromarray(imary1xy)
im1.save('pl_{}1.tif'.format(index))
im2 = Image.fromarray(imary2xy)
im2.save('pl_{}2.tif'.format(index))
im3 = Image.fromarray(imary3xy)
im3.save('pl_{}3.tif'.format(index))
im4 = Image.fromarray(imary4xy)
im4.save('pl_{}4.tif'.format(index))
```

Comment: ahh right so, I though by indexing the output I wouldn't have that issue. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to think about adding the filename reference, I used below into the output files that's in the penultimate line, so that your second loop doesn't overwrite the results of the first `im0.save('pl_{}_{}0.tif'.format(fname, index))`

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think this should do what you're aiming for:

Addition of a `number_of_shifts` variable, and then using that to iterate. Then the calls to np.roll are nested, which I think should work

```
list_frames = glob.glob('*.gif')
for index1, fname in enumerate(list_frames):
    im = Image.open(fname)
    shift=1
    number_of_shifts = 4
    image_list = []
    imary0 = np.array(im) # initial image (first layer)
    for _ in range(number_of_shifts):
        if not image_list:
            image_list.append(imary0)
        else:
            image_list.append(np.roll(np.roll(image_list[-1], shift, axis=0), shift, axis=1))
    for index2, img in enumerate(image_list):
        img.save("pl_{}_{}.tif".format(fname, index2))
    im.close()
```

Comment: cannot test it, but would deserve an upvote if it works since it's improving the OP code a great deal.

Comment: I like how you nested to the roll, I'll try implement but not today as I'm working to deadline and I'm afraid to introduce any more errors that I already have, thanks!